# Add an annotation to a class from a place other than class definition

Tags: java, annotations

I need to add an annotation to a class which is in a sperate dependency (in a separate jar) of the project that I am working on. I am wondering that can I do this in Java?

As an example, I need to add an annotation `HisClass` without touching the source code of `HisClass`.

```
public class HisClass{
   // ...
}
```

So, that the above class should be look like below at the build time,

```
@MyAnnot ( me = MyClass.class )
public class HisClass{
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways:

1. Write a compiler plugin for javac, and make it add the annotations. This will be quite difficult, as the plugin API has nearly no documentation.

2.(Maybe not possible) Inject the annotation after compiling. Add an extra buildstep after compiling and use a library like ASM to add this annotation to the classfile.